# R: Reordering geom_errorbarh put into gglot

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have the following CSV file:

```
group;response
stepOne;107
stepOne;946
stepTwo;184
stepTwo;456
...
```

I am reading it into dataframe, calculate the stats and reflect that stats on graph as errorbarsh. The code is the following

```
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)

# Read the input CSV file
data <- read.csv("~/Documents/r/input_file.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE)

x_axis_name <- names(data)[2]
y_axis_name <- names(data)[1]
title <- sprintf("Confidence interval for %s", names(data)[1])

# Calculate mean and confidence intervals for each group
group_stats <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(response),
    lower_ci_90 = mean - qt(0.90, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1)),
    upper_ci_90 = mean + qt(0.90, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1)),
    lower_ci_95 = mean - qt(0.95, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1)),
    upper_ci_95 = mean + qt(0.95, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1)),
    lower_ci_99 = mean - qt(0.99, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1)),
    upper_ci_99 = mean + qt(0.99, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1)),
    lower_ci_999 = mean - qt(0.999, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1)),
    upper_ci_999 = mean + qt(0.999, df = n() - 1) * (sd(response) / sqrt(n()-1))
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(group))

# Find absolute maximum from group_stats
limit_x_left = 0
limit_x_right <- 1.15*max(unlist(group_stats[, sapply(group_stats, is.numeric)]))

# Generate the graph
graph <- ggplot(group_stats, aes(y = group[order(group, decreasing=TRUE)], x = mean, color = group)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower_ci_90, xmax = upper_ci_90), height = 0.0, linewidth = 2.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower_ci_95, xmax = upper_ci_95), height = 0.0, linewidth = 2.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower_ci_99, xmax = upper_ci_99), height = 0.0, linewidth = 2.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  labs(x = x_axis_name, y = y_axis_name, title = title, color = "Legend") +
  xlim(limit_x_left, limit_x_right) +
  scale_color_manual(values = group_colors)


# Display the graph
print(graph)
```

No matter how I initially arrange group_stats dataframe, ggplot will put bars ordering them alphabetically DESC.

Trying to reorder it inside ggplot leads to nothing:
y = group[order(group, decreasing=FALSE)]
or
y = group[order(group, decreasing=TRUE)]
is being ignored.
[image]

However if I put
y = group[order(mean, decreasing=TRUE)] the values are being sorted by mean perfectly.
[image]

So, is there any way to change order of errorbars are being put onto plot? I want to order them alphabetically ASC.

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can include some sample data that allows the code to run and demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Do you get your desired outcome by loading the [forcats package](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/) (part of the tidyverse) and replacing `y = group[order(group, decreasing=TRUE)]` with `y = fct_rev(group)`?

Comment: Or you could try `y=reorder(group, mean, mean)` which recorders the levels of `group` (the first argument) by taking the mean (third argument) of the variable `mean` in the data (second argument).

Comment: @jared_mamrot, yes, forcats makes the deal. Not obvious solution for a newbie like me, but I know better. Thanks!
@DaveArmstrong, the solution with reorder doesn't work
`Error in geom_errorbarh():
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in get():
! object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @jared_mamrot, y = fct_rev(group) instead of y = group[order(group, decreasing=TRUE)] solves the issue. Need to install forcats:

`install.packages("forcats")`
(or `install.packages("tidyverse")`)

and add

`library(forcats)`

to the code.

Thanks @jared_mamrot

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :)